# Resolution of overloads at runtime for generics

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics, overloading

Is it possible in C# to pass a generic to an overloaded method, and get it to resolve to a non-generic version of the method?  For example:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        A a = new A();

        Process(a);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Process<T>(T item) {
        Writer(item);
    }

    // Writer methods...

    static void Writer<T>(T item) {
        Console.WriteLine("Type: " + item.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("You lose");
    }

    static void Writer(A item) {
        item.Write();
    }
}   

class A {
    public void Write() {
        Console.WriteLine("You found me!");
    }
}
```

This code outputs:

> Type: Foo.A
>
> You lose

And I'd like to see:

> You found me!

Is there any way of doing this, or something similar?  I'm using C# 4.

Comment: Why not use inheritance?

Comment: I doubt this is possible without an explicit cast or some additional code. In your `Process<T>`, `item` is of generic type `T`. There's no way the compiler would emit a call to a method expecting `A` as a type.

Comment: @WesleyWiser, well i'm basically trying to use this to call methods that take a `List<something>`... but I guess if I can't get overloading to work, I could write my own collection class, and inherit from it for each `something` I want to use.

Comment: @Eric so you want to do something for `List<A>` and something a little different for `List<B>`?

Comment: You could create an overload of `Process` which takes an `A` although that doesn't solve the general problem.

Comment: You might be able to use dynamic to have the overload be resolved at runtime in `Process<T>` i.e. `dynamic o = item; Writer(item);`

Comment: @Lee, that works! Changing `Process` to `Writer((dynamic)item);` works magically... I guess I need to read up on `dynamic` - care to add an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `dynamic` to defer overload resolution until runtime:

```
static void Process<T>(T item)
{
    dynamic d = item;
    Writer(d);
}
```